# Apache log analysis: I need to report the initial URI accessed in redirect chains

Tags: apache, log-analysis

An Apache log includes a line for each URI accessed, regardless of whether it is the first access in a redirect chain, just one of several along a redirect chain, or the URI finally served up with a status 200.

How can I generate a report showing just the first URI in each redirect chain. (For redirect chains of length one, then the first URI is the only URI. I need those included too.) I also need a count of the number of times each "first URI" was accessed.

Comment: Look at many log analysis tools that are available on the web and see when they produce.  For very basic results, you can run `webalizer`.  Other more complete tools (some sadly not free) will provide more detailed logs with full "path" analysis.

Comment: My problem is that there are lots of tools, but either I haven't stumbled on the right Google search criteria or there aren't tools that do precisely what I want. I thought maybe your term "path analysis" might due the trick, but that pulls up tools for tracking a user's clicks from page to page.